# Delete group when only two subgroup are null

Tags: sql, db2

From the below table I want to Delete all `2804 LMT_DED_TYP_ID` if only its subgroup CATGRY_ID 2,3 is having values is null (which means SL_NO (31703,31702,31704,31705,31706)), but it should not Delete other SL NO as 2 is not null for 2804

```
SL_NO   COVG_TYP_ID LMT_DED_TYP_ID  CATGRY_ID   VAL
31703   3000        2804            1           15
31702   3000        2804            2           (null)
31704   3000        2804            3           (null)
31705   3000        2804            4           14
31706   3000        2804            5           13
31707   3000        2804            1           16
31708   3000        2804            2           1
31709   3000        2804            3           (null)
31710   3000        2804            4           12
31711   3000        2804            5           11
```

I tried

```
Where SQ1.LMT_DED_TYP_ID = 2804
AND (SQ1.CATGRY_ID  = 2 AND SQ1.VAL IS NULL)
AND (SQ1.CATGRY_ID  = 3 AND SQ1.VAL IS NULL)
```

But this is not working please help

Comment: What if there's no row for category 1 or 2 for a SL_NO?

Comment: Hi @JayShankarGupta, in your question you ask: `if only its subgroup CATGRY_ID 2,3 is having values is null`. But in your query you check `SQ1.CATGRY_ID  = 1` and `SQ1.CATGRY_ID  = 2`. So what is the truth from this two statements ? Please edit. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Typo Error @VBoka, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

try like below using `exists`

```
delete from table_name t1
where exists
( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.LMT_DED_TYP_ID=t2.LMT_DED_TYP_ID
                    and t2.VAL is null
                     and CATGRY_ID in (2,3)
               having count(distinct CATGRY_ID)>=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will offer you one solution that is not very nice but it works ([Here is the DEMO so you can see it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=62c889f41580ca17956dd926d63e4bcc)):

```
delete from SQ1 where SL_NO in (
select t2.SL_NO from (SELECT p.SL_NO
                          , case when p.CATGRY_ID = 1 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+5)
                                 when p.CATGRY_ID = 2 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+4)
                                 when p.CATGRY_ID = 3 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+3)
                                 when p.CATGRY_ID = 4 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+2)
                                 else (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+1)
                            end gp
                   FROM SQ1 p) t2
where t2.gp = (select t1.gp 
               from (SELECT p.CATGRY_ID
                            , p.val
                            , lag(CATGRY_ID) OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID) li
                            , lag(val) OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID) lv
                            , case when p.CATGRY_ID = 1 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+5)
                               when p.CATGRY_ID = 2 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+4)
                               when p.CATGRY_ID = 3 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+3)
                               when p.CATGRY_ID = 4 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+2)
                               else (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+1)
                          end gp
                     FROM SQ1 p) t1
               where t1.CATGRY_ID = 3 
               and val is null 
               and li = 2 
               and lv is null));
```

I will explain now some parts of it. This next query creates a group based on row number + catgry_id and in that way is putting first 5 rows in a group of its own and doing that for every next 5 rows...Here it is very important to determin good order by.

```
SELECT p.CATGRY_ID
       , p.val
       , lag(CATGRY_ID) OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID) li
       , lag(val) OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID) lv
       , case when p.CATGRY_ID = 1 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+5)
              when p.CATGRY_ID = 2 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+4)
              when p.CATGRY_ID = 3 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+3)
              when p.CATGRY_ID = 4 then (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+2)
              else (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by COVG_TYP_ID ORDER BY p.LMT_DED_TYP_ID)+1)
         end gp
FROM SQ1 p
```

Then, when I have groups, I select group that does not have all you asked for:

```
where t1.CATGRY_ID = 3 
and val is null 
and li = 2 
and lv is null
```

After that I am deleting every ID that is a part of that group.
Probably this can be done with much les code lines but this does work. I will try to beautify it when I will have the chance...

Comment: @JayShankarGupta and ? Have you tried this option ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Where SQ1.LMT_DED_TYP_ID = 2804
AND (SQ1.CATGRY_ID  = 1 AND SQ1.VAL IS NULL)
OR (SQ1.CATGRY_ID  = 2 AND SQ1.VAL IS NULL)
```

You were trying to delete a row that has ID = 1 AND ID = 2 AND sq1.val1 si null AND sq1.val1 is null. There's no row that accomplishes that.

With the or you will solve that.